How to properly support an 18mm plywood desk top?
I am building a studio desk. I brought 2 large sheets of 18mm ply. I'm not wood savvy so it's just normal ply, not the brownish hardish ply but the lighter coloured one. I was going to double up 18mm and use that as the desktop but thought it might be overkill.
All the desk is is a top, 38x63 cls timber as a frame and stands that go like a box around the whole thing except the bottom front where my feet go, and a keyboard tray.
I've attached a basic pic of how I want it to look.
In your opinion, is the frame sufficient enough? It will hold a 30 inch monitor, 2 speakers, keyboard, couple of other things like drumpads etc. And the keyboard tray will hold a full 88key size piano keyboard.
I've also brought wood stain and them varnish to gloss it over after I've sanded it with very very light sand paper. The actual supporting frame (rectangle shape) that goes just under the ply, well I was just going to use wood glue and nails for that. It's softwood but do you guys think it will all be okay? I've seen people join wood at the corners using all sorts of techniques. I don't have a table saw I have a circular saw, jigsaw, dremel and other little bits. I don't want to go into the whole joinery thing it seems like a whole art to learn. I just want it to be safe and solid.
What do you guys think? Any suggestions or ammendments? I don't have anyone also I'm really just counting on strangers help off of the internet lol , thanks guys.
Sorry I forgot to add, the desk is 6ft long by 3 ft wide. Thanks also the tray that holds the keyboard will be out of ply. Thought maybe to double that up? Don't really know yet.

better ask here https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions

With those supports under it, it should hold up more weight than what you are planning.  Pick the best looking side without knotholes missing, and a bit of sanding might look good with just stain instead of painting it.

It'll probably hold the weight fine (hard to tell with such rough sketches), but you probably need some diagonal bracing for lateral loads—unless you anchor it to the wall.

Yes I've been told to put a diagonal length along the back to support the desk. I'll also put one at either side aswell.  Now the issue I have is the keyboard tray which will hold a full 88key size piano keyboard that weighs 14kg. I've made another post about it if you have any ideas.
